# Workfront value of NOW current datetime

Tags: attask

How to find current date time using work front Api, like value of $$NOW ? I have  used it as condition as plannedstartdate >  $$NOW, but how to know its value ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the API by the following.

```
GET    attask/api/v4.0/proj/search?apiKey=xxxxx&plannedStartDate=$$NOW&plannedStartDate_Mod=gt
```